# How to create multipe boxplots in one by only chosing certain rows from a data frame

Tags: r, boxplot

What I would like to do is creating several boxplots (all displayed in a single boxplot) *only from certain values* of my original data frame.

My data frame looks as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebBcs.jpg)

So now I want R to visualise **Parameter ~ Station** (Parameter are all variables coloured green and Station is the "station id")
Is there a way to tell R that I want all my Parameters on the x-axis **ONLY** for *BB0028* for example, which would mean that I only take the first 6 values of *mean_area*, *mean_area_exc, esd, feret, min and max* into account in the boxplot?
That would look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jILrv.jpg)

I tried it in very complicated way to add single boxplots one by one but I am sure there must be a more simple way.
This is what I tried:

```
bb28 <- df[c(1:6),]

bb28area <- boxplot(bb28$mean_area ~ bb28$BBnr)
bb28area_exc <- boxplot(bb28$mean_area_exc ~ bb28$BBnr)
bb28esd <- boxplot(bb28$mean_esd ~ bb28$BBnr)
bb28feret <- boxplot(bb28$mean_feret ~ bb28$BBnr)
bb28min <- boxplot(bb28$mean_min ~ bb28$BBnr)
bb28max <- boxplot(bb28$mean_max ~ bb28$BBnr)

boxplot(bb28$mean_area ~ bb28$BBnr)
boxplot(bb28$mean_area_exc ~ bb28$BBnr, add=TRUE, at = 1:1+0.45)
```

Also it doesn't look very nice because in the plot the x-axis does not adjust to the new boxplot which is cut off then:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywOcc.jpg)

I hope you can help me with simple a proper code to get my plot.

Thank you!
Cheers, Merle

Comment: post your sample data we could not retrieve from image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the function `multi.boxplot` below is what you are looking for. It uses base R only.

**Data.**
First, make up a dataset, since you have not provided us with one in a copy&paste friendly format.

```
set.seed(1234)

n <- 50
BBnr <- sort(sprintf("BB%04d", sample(28:30, n, TRUE)))
bb28 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:n, col2 = n:1, BBnr = BBnr)
tmp <- matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3)
colnames(tmp) <- paste("mean", c("this", "that", "other"), sep = "_")
bb28 <- cbind(bb28, tmp)
rm(BBnr, tmp)
```

**Code.**

```
multi.boxplot <- function(x, by, col=0, ...){
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  uniq.by <- unique(by)
  len <- length(uniq.by) - 1
  n <- ncol(x)
  n1 <- n + 1
  col <- rep(col, n)[seq_len(n)]
  boxplot(x[[ 1 ]] ~ by, at = 0:len*n1 + 1,
          xlim = c(0, (len + 1)*n1), ylim = range(unlist(x)), xaxt = "n", col=col[1], ...)
  for(i in seq_len(n)[-1])
    boxplot(x[[i]] ~ by, at = 0:len*n1 + i, xaxt = "n", add = TRUE, col=col[i], ...)
  axis(1, at = 0:len*n1 + n1/2, labels = uniq.by, tick = TRUE)
}

inx <- grep("mean", names(bb28))
multi.boxplot(bb28[inx], by = bb28$BBnr, col = rainbow(length(inx)))
```

[image]